# How can I find a string that is separated into two lines in the file where I want to find it?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need to look for a string in a text to know the line number in which it is located. My string is a single line that is divided into two lines in the file where I have to look for. Does anyone know how I can look for it? Thanks

My file.txt

```
Title number 1
Some random text
```

I need to find things like "number 1 Some random", "1 Some random"...

This is my code that only works if everything is in one line:

```
doc="file.txt"
text="number 1 Some random"
line=$(awk 'NR == awkvar='$text'' $doc)
```

Any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Comment: I expect to get the line number where the string is located. In this case it would be 1

Comment: any chance the search string could be spread across more than 2 lines? I don't see how you can say your code *works if everything is in one line* since I get (as expected) a syntax error: `awk: fatal: cannot open file '1' for reading: No such file or directory`

Comment: Use the N and D commands of sed. See [https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Text-search-across-multiple-lines.html](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Text-search-across-multiple-lines.html).

Comment: Does the string it matches NEED to be split across 2 lines or is it OK if it exists all on 1 line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS=": " }
NR>1 {
    cur = prev " " $0
    if ( index(cur,tgt) ) {
        print NR-1, cur
    }
}
{ prev = $0 }
```

```
$ awk -v tgt='number 1 Some random' -f tst.awk file
1: Title number 1 Some random text
```

If you ONLY want the line number printed then, of course, only do `print NR-1`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & bash):

```
file="file.txt"
text="number 1 Some random"
line=$(($(sed -n 'N;/'${tgt// /\\s}'/!D;=;q' "$file")-1))
```

Build a regexp from `text` and use it in a sed script to report the line number of the match of the regexp.

N.B. If the match occurs within one line only the line number may be off by 1.